# Build website in 2 language where in user enters his data also

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I have got idea of how to build a website in 2 languages, i have a switch and each language text in file and user it. But my website is a website where all freelancers register and post their projects and so. How do i control in what language users enter data. If user entered data in English, how do i show data in other language ?

Example: take 2 language English and Arabic

Case 1 :
1. User enters data only in english.
2. How do i show this data in Arabic??

Case 2: 
1. How to make user enter data only in either Arabic or English??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much content there is you may need to employ a dedicated translator.

I wouldn't suggest automatic translation or at least be very, very careful with it, as users don't like that at all (e.g. I definitely prefer reading text in English than an automated translation in my native language that some website oh so helpfully decided to show me based on my IP).

Comment: You mean to say, let user enter only in english ??

Comment: I mean that if you have two languages to maintain, then the users should enter their data in one of those two. You would have to take care of appropriate translation. Not many are able to express the same content well in two languages (I tried for a while but failed and he translated variant was always inferior, regardless of whether I started with German or English).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the site settings, you will have to use a language translator and set it up on your website accordingly.